# What happens when I clear a vector of struct?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stdmap

memory management question here.

I got a `vector` of a struct `Test1`, this struct contains a `map`. In my program, functions will locally create `Test1`s that with locally created maps.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct Vec3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

struct Test1 {
    int64_t a;
    std::map<int, Vec3> mapy;
};

std::vector<Test1> global;

void ClearGlobal() {
    global.clear();
}

void AddToGlobal() {
    Vec3 test = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::map<int, Vec3> mapy;
    mapy[1] = test;
    global.push_back({ 10, mapy });
}

void main() {
    AddToGlobal();
    ClearGlobal();
}
```

I wonder what will happen when I clear that vector? will all the structs get free from memory too?

Comment: Yes, every `Test1` and its members will be destroyed. Your `global` vector's size will be set to 0 but the capacity will be what it used to be.

Comment: If you want to test it, you can write a destructor, `~Vec3()`, that prints a diagnostic message.

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by _get free from memory_. The memory itself used by the vector (its buffer) will not be freed, just the objects (elements) will be destructed. This destruction will also destruct inner maps, which will free any memory dynamically allocated by them.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder what will happen when I clear that vector?

As per documentation, the elements are erased.

> will all the structs get free from memory too?

The capacity of the vector does not change.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: the memory of the `mapy` field of `Test1` will be freed, but the memory of the struct itself remains.

**Long answer**:

Clearing the vector calls the destructor of the objects inside the vector, but does not free the objects. Here is a snippet from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear):

> Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged

This means that `capacity()` elements of size `sizeof(Test1)` are not freed. But since the destructor is called, the inner fields such as `mapy` are destroyed. Since `mapy` owns some memory on the heap, its destruction frees that memory. As a result, all memory of `Test1` which is pointed to the heap outside of `Test1` is freed.

Note that this freeing is happening only due to the destructors of the inner fields. If your struct contains a raw-pointer to a memory block, and if `Test1::~Test1` does not explicitly delete it, then that block of memory will not be freed after the call to `clear()`. This might result in a memory leak.

**EDIT**: Seeing another answer, I'd like to stress that after `clear()` no element is valid anymore, even though none is freed. You are not supposed to read or write them, other than through methods that recreate the elements in the vector (such as `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `resize`, and `insert`). Any other access to element, after calling `clear()` is undefined behavior, which can result in weird and unpredictable program behavior (mostly due to confusing the compiler by breaking its assumption that the code does not rely on undefined behavior). Never rely on undefined behavior. Never invoke undefined behavior, knowingly, even if that "*seems to work*" today.